# can I call react function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have create react app, in this react app create one function name is checkPrimeNumber(), this function takes number as an argument and return true or false. after that using npm run build i have create bundle js and this bundle js link to my html file now my question is how to access checkPrimeNumber() function in my html file??

i have link bundle in html file and try to access checkPrimeNumber() but i'm not able to access checkPrimeNumber() function in my html file

Comment: Would you post your HTML code?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any codes, but was your js file imported into the HTML?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of bundle js and window object may be different hence you're not able to reach the function. Better to make it available to window object.

`window.checkPrimeNumber = checkPrimeNumber`

That way you can call this function from your html as well.

Comment: i have also try this solution still i am not able to solve the problem